# Unable pass test for no 'li' in 'ul' using Enzyme and Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsx, enzyme

Simple todo list app to get started with Jest and Enzyme.

In App.js I am rendering the following component where props.list is equal to an empty array on the state.

```
export const Ul = ({list}) => {
    return (
        <ul className="list" >
          {list.map((item,i) => <li key={i}>{item}</li> )}
        </ul>
    ) 
}
```

Viewing it in Chrome the element renders as expected.

```
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

Viewing the dom generated by Enzyme in the console using `wrapper.debug()`  the component is rendering as:

```
    <Ul list={{...}}>
        <ul className="list" />
    </Ul>
```

I find that odd and don't know why.

My problem is I am unable to pass a test checking for no 'li' children within the UL with the following:

```
it('ul initially has no children', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.find('.list').children()).to.have.lengthOf(0);
    // const ul = wrapper.find('.list');
    // expect(ul).toHaveLength(0); 
})
```

I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined" which makes me think it's not finding the

in the first place.

Am I just incorrectly using the jest/enzyme api?

Comment: The tests are weird. Why do you mount `App` instead of `Ul`?

Comment: My intentions were to mount App, simulate a change event and then check the state and contents of the list. I could mount Ul and give it an empty array, but I don't see the point of that. Of course it's going to be empty.

Comment: You don't simulate any change events within the test case, that's why I don't understand the situation - and I can't even see your `App` component, thereby I can't give you more precise suggestions. I'd just rather test the `Ul` component individually in this case.

Comment: Just to clarify too, if I simulate an event that updates the state, ( a todo item is added) I can only test that the state has been changed. I cannot test that the ul now has that item correct?

Answer (score 3):

The method is incorrect.

```
  expect(wrapper.find('.list').children()).to.have.lengthOf(0);
```

Should really :

```
  expect(wrapper.find('.list').children()).toHaveLength(0);
```

Comment: Yest, it works and looks good, but I can't figure out why it doesn't with incorrect example though it emerges from official documentation https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/children.html?